# How to recieve inner HTML of a child node in selenium (python)?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I'm trying to iterate through multiple nodes and receive various child nodes from the parent nodes. Assuming that I've something like the following structure:

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="item">
        <div class="item-footer">
            <div class="item-type">Some data in here</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- More items listed here -->
</div>
```

I'm able to receive all child nodes of the wrapper container by using the following.

```py
wrapper = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div')
items = wrapper.find_elements(By.XPATH, './/*')
```

Anyways I couldn't figure out how I can now receive the inner HTML of the container containing the information about the item type. I've tried this, but this didn't work.

```py
for item in items:
    item_type = item.item.find_element(By.XPATH, './/div/div').get_attribute('innerHTML')
    print(item_type)
```

This results in the following error:

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element:
```

Does anybody knows how I can do that?

Comment: It would be great if you provide few more child nodes with your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case all the elements their content you want to get are `div`  with `class` attribute value `item-type` located inside `div`s with `class` attribute value `item-footer` you can simply do the following:

```py
elements =  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="item-footer"]//div[@class="item-type"]')
for element in elements:
    data = element.get_attribute('innerHTML')
    print(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `BeautifulSoup` after getting page source from selenium to easily scrape the HTML data.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# selenium code part
# ....
# ....
# driver.page_source is the HTML result from selenium

html_doc = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
items = html_doc.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'item'})
for item in items:
    text = item.find('div', attrs={'class':'item-type'}).text
    print(text)
```

Output:

```
Some data in here
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to just find the relative `xpath` to identify each element and then iterate it.

```
items = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='wrapper']//div[@class='item']//div[@class='item-type']")
for item in items:
    print(item.text)
    print(item.get_attribute('innerHTML'))
```

Or use the `css` selector

```
items = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".wrapper >.item .item-type")
for item in items:
    print(item.text)
    print(item.get_attribute('innerHTML'))
```